# The Microsoft Store rejects my Code Signing as "weak". How do I sign a VB6 msi for the store?

Tags: windows-installer, code-signing, microsoft-store

I have been trying to upload my legacy VB6 application to the Microsoft Store. I have purchased and used a valid Code Signing Certificate. In January this was apparently accepted by the store submission process. Since 1st February it rejects my certificate saying that the signing is "weak".

I can only find references to weak vs strong as in "Strong Naming" in relation to submitting from Visual Studio.  I cannot find any reference to exactly how I can resolve this problem outside of Visual Studio

I had assumed that running signtool.exe, using a Certificate that chains back correctly to a Certificate Authority accepted by the Microsoft Trust network, would work but the submission is still rejected by the store. I have used signtool verify to confirm that the msi is correctly signed and timestamped as required.

I have been in contact with Microsoft support who seemed to indicate a problem with certain OCX files which are issued and already signed by Microsoft. It may be that I may need to sign every exe, ocx etc (including those from Microsoft themselves) as MD5 is not acceptable and SHA256 is required.

Has anyone recently submitted a legacy msi to the Store successfully using a third-party Code Signing Certificate? Any guidance as to what my next step should be would be welcomed.

David

Comment: What digest algorithm did you use when signing?

Comment: SHA256.    Since then I have tried out what I proposed - I signed every ocx,dll,exe whether mine or Microsoft.  I then built the MSI and signed this.  The preliminary validation of my application now passes.  I have now submitted it for formal evaluation.  I will post the outcome here.

Comment: I have worked out how to do this and posted a full question/answer detailing all the steps required.  See https://stackoverflow.com/q/78107179/23490659